# Notification not coming from an Android service

Tags: android

I have a service class that receives message from server and I should notify the user about the message. I got this code from internet for showing notification -

```
public void showNotification(String msg){
        logger.debug("GOT NEW TEXT MESSAGE0: " + msg);
        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);
        logger.debug("GOT NEW TEXT MESSAGE1: " + msg);
        Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("New Message Received")
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .addAction(0, "Ok", pIntent).build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, n);
    }
```

As per the logs, I am getting the message correctly -

```
GOT NEW MESSAGE0: hello
GOT NEW MESSAGE1: hello
```

But still I am not getting any notification. Is there any problem in my code.

Comment: are you getting any excecption??

Comment: No.. my code is running fine without exceptions

Comment: try adding `.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)` to your notification builder.

Comment: Is that a necessary field?

Comment: I've heard that notifications wont pop up if  no icons are set.

Comment: Ok I just tried with .setSmallIcon(0) but still did not work.

Comment: Where do you call `showNotification` from?

Comment: I call it from the thread that receives message from the server.

Comment: Why are you giving `.setSmallIcon(0)`?? It will not work with that. Pass a drawable resource or an icon. Try the answer given by @cliff. If you miss certain properties in the `Notification.Builder` notification wont show up.

Comment: But what class is that? Is it an Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although (as far as i know) it is not documented, notifications need their small icon set in order to show.

Try the following:

```
Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info) // this is required
    .setContentTitle("New Message Received")
    .setContentText(msg)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .addAction(0, "Ok", pIntent).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Sample.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ResultActivity.class);
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

            b.setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setTicker("Hearty365")
                    .setContentTitle("Default notification")
                    .setContentText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
                    //.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setContentInfo("Info")
            .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause, "Start", contentIntent)
                    .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert, "Pause", contentIntent);



            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(1, b.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling `PendingIntent.getActivity()` provide a flag (i.e. `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`) instead of just `0`.

Reference to all possible constants: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html